# Reading properties file with configparser in python

Tags: python, configparser

So I have a working python script that properly executes and reads from a properties file. Below is an example of reading and using the properties file:

```
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('file.ini')
blah = config.get('DEFAULT', 'protocol')
```

Again, this works on my machine. I have just recently tried running this same script on a remote machine and keep getting error: `Exception: No option 'protocol' in section: 'DEFAULT`. I have also tried accessing the values with `blah = config['DEFAULT']['protocol']` but to no avail.

Here is an example properties file:

```
[DEFAULT]
protocol = http
```

To the best of my knowledge I have properly formatted the file and am using the correct python implementation, but have no clue as to why I am receiving this exception when it is clearly there. Is there any other way to read config file? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Is this Python 2 or 3? Also, did you create the file on Windows with `\r\n` line endings and it worked locally but not on a remote machine running Unix?

Comment: Also, are you sure `file.ini` is actually in the current working directory? What does `config.read` return? (It should be a list of filenames that were found; if you get back `[]`, it didn't find anything.)

Comment: As a side note, it's pretty rare that you actually _want_ to read config files from the current working directory. `~/file.ini` or a nice-for-each-platform path or within the script's directory are more likely to be useful.

Comment: `file.ini` was for simplicity. The full file path is provided as an argument to my script. My machine is osx currently but I will try the different line endings and see. I am running python 2.6.9 on my machine and 2.6.6 on the remote box.

Comment: Great, but I still want to know whether `config.read` returns a list of the one file you passed in, or an empty list.

Comment: @abarnert You are right, on my machine it returns a list with the file name while the remote box returns empty brackets. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Is there actually a file at the specified path? Maybe a typo somewhere? Or you used `~` and forgot the `os.path.expanduser`?